# Receiving input value and some other data together in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom input component that looks like this:

```
<select @change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
...
</select>
```

As you can see I am emitting a `change` event with the current input value (hence, `$event.target.value`).

I use that component like this:

```
<mycomponent @change="someMethod"></mycomponent>
```

as you can see, the value is automatically received by `someMethod`. In my root vue instance I have this `someMethod` defined:

```
someMethod(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

But what if I wanted to pass some other value to the `someMethod` method along with the input value? How can I do that?

```
<mycomponent @change="someMethod('My String Data')"></mycomponent>
```

How can I receive both the input value and 'My String Data' in `someMethod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the emitted event’s value in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special `$event` variable:

```
<mycomponent @change="someMethod($event, 'My String Data')"></mycomponent>
```